# oroCommerce/Symfony 2.8 - how to add a custom field to a registration form

Tags: php, symfony, orocommerce

Does anyone know a way to add an extra field (VAT ID provided by the Infinitepay Bundle) to oroCommerce's registration form? I can't find a way to do it.

The issue is that this field isn't part of the CustomerUser entity, but of the associated Customer entity. So the normal builder->add() command doesn't work. I'm also having trouble finding a way to put any code into a Bundle of my own and get it to work (instead of hacking the core). I've already read the Symfony docs, but they didn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create symfony form extension, see [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/create_form_type_extension.html)

Then add the VAT ID field to form builder and add a POST_SUBMIT listener with a lower priority than [this one](https://github.com/oroinc/customer-portal/blob/2.6/src/Oro/Bundle/CustomerBundle/Form/Type/FrontendCustomerUserRegistrationType.php#L143)

In the listener's code, you can map the VAT ID value to the Customer entity.

**UPD:**

> 1. How exactly am I supposed to use form type extensions?

Ok. Use this [gist](https://gist.github.com/bemzaslava/b10dc988296d8ebc76791e946aec5ffa)

> The documentation says they are good for extending field types, not forms.

It's the same. Any form type can be used as a child (field) of another form type.

> I can't do it with $builder->add() - that gives me a 500 error because the entity doesn't have that field.

You should add an option 'mapped => false' for your field. See [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/form.html#mapped)

> I also need a way to put it in a bundle of my own, not into the core.

You can modify any form type from your own bundle using form type extensions. This is what they were created for.

Comment: 1. How exactly am I supposed to use form type extensions? The documentation says they are good for extending field types, not forms. 2. How exactly do I add the VAT ID field? I can't do it with $builder->add() - that gives me a 500 error because the entity doesn't have that field. I also need a way to put it in a bundle of my own, not into the core.

Comment: If it will help - please, resolve your thread in forum https://oroinc.com/orocommerce/forums/topic/how-to-add-additional-field-to-registration-form

Comment: I just tried the following: https://gist.github.com/Koks-A-Cola/a2c30ccd755462a01b767b33db102bb6 but it didn't work. ("XXXXX" is a placeholder for the name of the company). Maybe I'm putting the services.yml in the wrong path? So far, I've tried: "src/XXXXX/Bundle/VATBundle/Resources/config", "src/XXXXX/Bundle/VATBundle/Resources/config/oro", and "app/config".

Comment: Probably you didn't load your services.yml file. See documentation https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/bundles/extension.html

You can use any oro bundle as an example. For example look at this parts https://github.com/oroinc/orocommerce/blob/1.6/src/Oro/Bundle/PromotionBundle/DependencyInjection/OroPromotionExtension.php#L24
https://github.com/oroinc/orocommerce/blob/1.6/src/Oro/Bundle/PromotionBundle/OroPromotionBundle.php#L22

Comment: Just did that. It won't compile now (I tried both cache:clear and cache:warmup). Error is: [ReflectionException] Property Oro\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User::$avatar does not exist

Comment: Try to remove caches at all. 'rm -rf app/cache/*'

Comment: Issue has been resolved, thanks. It hasn't worked because my VM corrupted its filesystem somehow (had to reinstall it).